# Countifs Formula Partial Text within Cell Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I am looking to create a formula that does a countif(s) that includes partial text and is within a range of cells. This will be used to filter survey results based on a range of training sessions.

[Here is a sample spreadsheet I am working with].[1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gzukdf6sIgTn158DpFrHQE6Tiw6kD2t01SCyh_iy2kc/edit#gid=0)

I want a total count of people who selected "Major" in Answers (Column C), but also in the range of Dashboard (Column A), which will be partial text. I will be doing this for columns C-H of the "Answers tab"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=countifs(Answers!C:C, "Major", index(--regexmatch(Answers!B:B,textjoin("|",1,A2:A))), 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already have a working solution for each row, you can also consolidate it with BYROW, and SUM the values of each result:

```
=SUM(BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(each,COUNTIFS(Answers!C:C, "Major", Answers!B:B, "*" & each & "*" ))))
```

[image]